# Should I leave a database connection open for an event handler?

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection-pooling

I am writing an application in C# that will connect to a PostgreSQL database via ODBC.  The database will be on the same machine as my application.  My application will have an event handler that could fire a few times a second.  The handler will write two values into a database table.  I'm wondering if I should open a database connection once when the application starts for the event handler to use, or if I should open it inside the event handler and close it when the handler is finished with its work.

If connection pooling is used, the question becomes moot, since an existing connection would always be used if one is available, and I could just open and close the connection without worrying about slowing down my application.  But it seems that the ODBC driver for PostgreSQL does not support connection pooling. Or does it?

I'm using the PostgreSQL Unicode driver version 9.03.04.00.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why use ODBC when native drivers are available?

Comment: The only reason you would want to close and re-open is because you are running out of database connection capacity.  Is that a possibility here?

Comment: Steve, I meant to mention that.  We use ODBC because some customers want to use some database provider other than PostgreSQL, and as long as an ODBC driver is available, we don't have to change our applicaton.

Comment: Hoodaticus, I am more concerned about speed.  I don't want opening and closing the database to end up being a bottelneck.

Comment: I suggest to use some kind of ORM to manage the database details like the provider in use. For example with EntityFramework you should be free from this problem (users with different database systems) unless you use some very specific vendor capabilities not available in other systems. (But then ODBC or not you will have troubles switching database system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* open and close a database connection for every request. It may work as long as there is little traffic, but it is a receipe for disaster otherwise.

You can use an external connection pool like pgBadger, but if that is overkill in your case, just leave the connection open. With several writes per second that is clearly the right thing to do.